# Commit all transforms (pressing enter or clicking the tick, once)

Tags: photoshop-cs6

I want to use [Photoshop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Photoshop) to make a GIF file. If I have to place 120 images, I have to keep pressing enter (commit transform for each) until I'm done with all of them.

Is there a way to skip all of this (say, accept all of them at once)?

Comment: You may want to check out this solution. http://tv.adobe.com/watch/understanding-adobe-photoshop-cs6/batch-processing/

Answer (score 1):

From [Adobe help page](http://helpx.adobe.com/en/photoshop/using/processing-batch-files.html)

Do one of the following:

1. Choose File > Automate > Batch (Photoshop)
2. Specify the action you want to use to process files from the Set and Action pop-up menus. The menus display actions available in the Actions panel. You may need to choose a different set or load a set in the panel if you don’t see your action.
3. Choose the files to process from the Source pop-up menu:

   - Folder: Processes files in a folder you specify. Click Choose to locate and select the folder.
   - Import: Processes images from a digital camera, scanner, or a PDF document.
   - Opened Files: Processes all open files. **this is the most likely**
4. Set processing, saving, and file naming options. For descriptions of the Batch dialog box settings [see Batch and droplet processing options](http://helpx.adobe.com/en/photoshop/using/processing-batch-files.html#batch_and_droplet_processing_options).